# How to make it so that when a node in the list changes, it changes in the tree? C#

Tags: c#, reference, binary-tree

I need to to initialize binary tree wide (to the maximum filling each layer)

I tried to use BFS algorithm to find first needed node (leftmost and topmost). But I came across that element of the list doesn't change original node. How can I get what I want?

Node code

```
public class Node<T>
    {
        public T Data
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public Node(T data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }

        public Node<T> Parent { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Left { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Right { get; set; }
    }
```

Tree code

```
public class Tree<T>
    {
        public Node<T> root;

        public void CreateRoot(T data)
        {
            root = new (data);
        }

        public void Add(T data, Node<T> node)
        {
            if (root != null)
            {
                List<Node<T>> list = new () { node };
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) 
                {
                    if (list[i] != null)
                    {
                        list.Add(node.Left);
                        list.Add(node.Right);
                        list[i + 1].Parent = list[i];
                        list[i + 2].Parent = list[i];
                        list.RemoveAt(i);
                        --i;
                    } else
                    {
                        list[i] = new (data);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Change what? And how did you change the original node?

Comment: @shingo, i don't know how to change the original node. This is the crux of the matter. I find required in the list, but i need to change it in the tree

Comment: You haven't told me what you want to change.

Comment: In your tree you have `root` field, but in code of `Add` you never do anything to it (just check for null) - maybe it should be somehow assigned?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Add` method is just broken.

Lets assume you call the add method, with some piece of data and the root node as arguments.

```
list.Add(node.Left);
list.Add(node.Right);
```

Both left and right are null in this case. so the list will contain `{root, null, null}`

```
list[i + 1].Parent = list[i];
list[i + 2].Parent = list[i];
```

This should throw a null reference exception, since `list[i + 1]` should be null. If that does not happen I might have missunderstood something.

```
list[i] = new (data);
```

So you are adding the new data to the list, but how does that help? the list will be out of scope when the method ends. You are never assigning your new data object to the parents left/right nodes.

Note that a binary tree is just a tree structure where every node has two childs. In most cases we add additional rules to the tree, like every child has to be larger than its parent, to actually make use of the tree.

We typically do not want the users of our tree to know or care about nodes, we should instead have an interface with methods like `Add(T)`, `int Count`, `T PopSmallest()`, `T PeekSmallest()`, to let our user use the tree. How the tree is implemented is an internal detail.

While it might seem attractive to use classes/objects to represent nodes in the tree, in most cases trees are used for performance reasons. Using objects are often not great for performance, since they will add memory overhead, and will distribute nodes all over your memory, preventing efficient cache usage. For some types of binary trees you can just use an array.

See [this article](https://egorikas.com/max-and-min-heap-implementation-with-csharp/) for an introduction how to design a min/max heap, one of the more useful binary trees in my opinion. It should not be very difficult to extend the implementation to be generic.